# Is there a way to tell what may be blocking a Flask/Python application, or pip command, from running?

Tags: python, flask, pip, cygwin

My company has pushed some updates to my team's computers and they seem to have broken our application we are developing.  Up until these updates, we were able to run pip install/uninstall commands, our apps "flask run ..." command, and python scripts just fine.  After the updates, the commands return immediately after executing them, without performing the task and providing no error output.

I tried uninstalling Flask/Python, which led me to discover the fact that pip uninstall wasn't working.  Upon a reboot, I discovered that the very first command executed runs fine, and then after that, they start acting as detailed above.

I have tried debugging the application itself, but it is almost like after the first pip/flask/python command is executed, something starts killing the process before it has a chance to do anything.

Is there any way to generate logs or to tell what may be blocking these commands from executing?

I can provide more context/details as necessary, just not sure what would be relevant or not.

System details -
OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.9.16
Flask: 2.2.3
Werkzeug: 2.2.3

Comment: Do you know what was updated on the team's devices that caused this issue? If there are any error messages, please include information about those as well. At present, I'm not sure where to start, but with this additional information I may be able to help!

Comment: @AaronTook I am really not sure what was updated on our devices, just that IT forced a reboot a few times this week.  I am thinking there might have been a policy change in there that is blocking something.

There are no error messages output, the command simply "executes" and then returns immediately, with no output.  This happens for both flask and pip commands.

In other news, I did some testing and I believe this to be a result of us using Cygwin to run these scripts, and whatever is broken/blocked lies in there, as when I installed python/flask on my base machine, everything works.

Comment: Look to see if they switched from a pip install to a cygwin package install.

Comment: Pip executes the config.py file, so look there from anythin unexpected.